# MySQL Query problem (duplicate results)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

Im having a problem finding duplicate results in a mysql database (a cocktail recipe website). Here the setup:

Table 1: 'cocktail'
[cid,c_name] (cid = unique cocktail id, c_name = cocktail name)

Table 2: 'ingredients':
[iid,i_name] (iid = unique ingredient id, i_name = ingredient name)

Table 3: 'cocktail_ingredients' (the linking table)
[ciid,cid,iid] (ciid = unique row identifier, cid = cocktail cid, iid = ingredient iid)

So one cocktail can have multiple rows in the 'cocktail_ingredients' table (1 to many).

Setup is fine. The problem Im having now is finding if there are duplicate cocktails in my database.

For instance if the cocktail_ingredients table had these entries:

cid | iid
1 | 56
1 | 78
1 | 101
.
.
.
9 | 56
9 | 78
9 | 101

The cocktail is the same (for theoretical purposes here anyway).

If the 'cocktail_ingredients' table had one more row ...

9 | 103

Then it wouldn't be the same, as cocktail number 9 includes an extra ingredient.

So the mysql has to do 2 checks, firstly that the ingredient count is the same, and secondly that every ingredient id (iid) is the same for corresponding cocktails (cid).

Im stumped on this one, any help much appreciated. I'm thinking I might have to head down the PHP route as well to code in something more complex, but I'm struggling there as well so thought this would be a good place to stop and ask.

Thanks a ton

Nick

Comment: Just because two cocktails contain the same ingredients they are not necessarily the same cocktail. Quantities could vary.

Comment: Yeah I understand this - thats why I said "for theoretical purposes". Obviously the way you mix, the amounts and a host of other variables can alter it. But it certainly gives me a good base to start looking through.

Answer (score 1):

You may recall from a distant math class that the definition of set equality is that both A abd B are subsets of one another (non-strict) so just create a view or procedure that checks if every thin that is in A is also in B, then check the two cocktails are both subsets of one another. This is far from a complete answer, but it may be enough to get you going ;)

it will probably be easier to do the negation - find an ingredient in A that is not in B. none exist, then A must be a strict subset of B (assuming A and B can't both be empty)

Alternatively do a count of each ingredient in A, each ingredient ion B and each ingredient in A and B then if they are equal they are equivalent cocktails

```
CREATE VIEW ingredient_count AS
SELECT cid, count(*) as ingredients
FROM cocktail_ingredients
GROUP BY cid

CREATE VIEW shared_ingredients AS
SELECT c1.cid cid1, c2.cid cid2, count(*) as ingredients
FROM cocktail_ingredients as c1 INNER JOIN cocktail_ingredients as c2 
ON (c1.cid != c2.cid AND c1.iid = c2.iid)
GROUP BY c1.cid,c2.cid

CREATE VIEW duplicates AS
SELECT cid1,cid2
FROM (ingredient_count AS ic1 INNER JOIN shared_ingredients
        ON ic1.cid=cid1) INNER JOIN ingredient_count as ic2
     ON ic2.cid=cid2
WHERE ic1.ingredients=ic2.ingredients
AND   shared_ingredients=ic1.ingredients
```

Note this may be much faster in mysql with subselects with sensible where clauses rather than views, but this is easier to understand

Comment: Thanks a ton, looks good, and my Math class memories are slowly coming back to me. I'll have a go later, fingers crossed.

Comment: I think it works, but way to slow for my database size (cocktail table hold 3000 records, cocktail_ingredients holds over 12000, and ingredients holds around 650). Im working on a PHP solution, but again its tricky ....

Comment: @Nick, see my note at the bottom - you'll be able to speed this up a lot by using sub-queries instead of the views (with appropriate where clauses) i wrote that for readability not speed. In my experience this kind of query can go from 30+ seconds to a small fraction of a second if done right.

Answer (score -1):

You can impose such checking using [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).
But, yet there is a conceptual problem.

Say, you have two cocktails  `{1 | 56, 78, 101}` and `{9 | 56, 78, 101, 103}` and also assume that you have implemented the check.

Now, you are inserting data for 1:

```
cid |  iid
----------
1   |  56
```

Then, add rest two ingredients...

```
cid |  iid
----------
1   |  56
1   |  78
1   | 101
```

Fine, now you start adding 9:

```
cid |  iid
----------
1   |  56
1   |  78
1   | 101
9   |  56
```

You have three more ingredients, so continue adding them:

```
cid |  iid
----------
1   |  56
1   |  78
1   | 101
9   |  56
9   |  78
```

Two more remaining (101,103)
But alas! You cannot add 101! If you try to add 101, then 9 would become identical to 1, which your trigger will prevent you from adding.

When a cocktail is subset of another, you have to add the subset later. I hope I could make you understand this.

You should not put any restriction in database. What I would do in my web application is:

1. In the cocktail entry/update interface, I would take user input (and not yet insert/update in DB)
2. When user clicks the save button (I would add a save button), check if the new/updated cocktail becomes copy of another (May be I would write a stored procedure, but it can be found using a select query only)
3. If the new/updated cocktail is not duplicate of another, insert/update database. If

Comment: -1 for You should not put any restriction in database - this is the worst advice i have ever heard.

Comment: Its not for restrictions for adding, just for cleansing up existing entries. I may put in some notification that it "may" be the same, but wouldn't stop it by default.

Comment: @tobyodevis: plz read the entie answer. you will find that i said db restriction can be implemented. but in the end, i suggested something else. Anyways, using trigger is a very common practise by oracle dba's. though its the worst thing u have heard

Comment: nowhere was it suggested that he wanted to _prevent_ the addition of 'identical' cocktails - he made it pretty obvious to me with the 'theoretical purposes' comment that he just wants a list he can hand check and merge as appropriate. As such an SQL solution is preferable to talking about triggers and then not using them... and  "You should not put _any_ restriction in the database" is a bad idea, perhaps _this_ restriction is a bad one, but in general they are pretty useful